# A basic Vue JS search filter that isn't case sensitive or lowercase only in array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have made a basic search filter in Vue JS to filter some blog posts based on the title. However, it raises some issues regarding how the user searches against what is stored in each string in my array.

For example, is it best practice to write the string in the array in lowercase?

If not essential, then presently when a user searches 'sports' nothing is returned. If however the user searches 'Sports' the right result is shown.

Therefore, as a user won't know to capitalize the first letter when using the search input field is there a way to not have a case sensitive search to avoid this problem?

```
      <h1>Blog Search</h1>
      <input type="text" id="search" v-model="search" placeholder="Search blogs">
      <ul>
          <li v-for="blog in filteredBlogs">
             <h2>{{blog.title}}</h2>
          </li>
      </ul>
```

My script is as below

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            search:'',
            blogs: [
              { title: 'How to take photographs' },
              { title: 'Sports from around the world' }
            ]
        };
    },
    computed: {
        filteredBlogs: function(){
            return this.blogs.filter((blog) => {
                return blog.title.match(this.search);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your object title to lowercase first and your search text to lower case then search it:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            search:'',
            blogs: [
              { title: 'How to take photographs' },
              { title: 'Sports from around the world' }
            ]
        };
    },
    computed: {
        filteredBlogs: function(){
            return this.blogs.filter((blog) => {
                return blog.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer works and I now understand.

Answer (score 1):

The filter blogs function can be written like this

```
       filteredBlogs: function(){
            return this.blogs.filter((blog) => {
                return blog.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. Very much appreciated.